# When is accessed DB with EntityFramework for IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I work with EF in .NET Core and let's say I have Students DbSet. I know I will have max 50 students in the Db. I want to do some operation where I use data from almost every student.

```
...
foreach(var x in xs)
{
      var student = context.Students.Where(...x...).FirstOrDefault();
      ...
}
```

This approach will access DB n-times for every x in the cycle. To optimize this I want to access DB just once and have records in the memory. I got this idea.

```
...
var students = context.Students.AsNoTracking();
foreach (var x in xs)
{
    var student = students.Where(...x...).FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}
```

In this case, the `students` is IQueryable. My question is - Will this solve the problem? Will the DB be accessed just once on `context.Students.AsNoTracking();` and the records will be loaded to memory, or the DB will be accessed every time I call `students.Where(...x...).FirstOrDefault();` and why?

Of course, I can use `context.Students.ToList()`, but I want to know, how IQueryable works.

Comment: *I want to know, how IQueryable works* -- That's too broad to answer here, but all you need to know is the difference between deferred and forced execution. It's easy to find which LINQ methods force execution.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you, the "deferred and forced execution" was the key for googling :D So to be clear, in my case the students property is just deferred until I call FirstOrDefault(), am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So still n queries.